# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer working in developpement mode but not in prod

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, unexpected-token, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I use ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to display pdf files from API 9(blob), everythink work fine in localhost, but after deployment, the file is not displayed I get this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.8d7f0b54d7450531.js:1 If you see the error message "expected expression, got '='" above: you can safely ignore it as long as you know what you're doing. It means your browser is out-of-date. Please update your browser to benefit from the latest security updates and to enjoy a faster PDF viewer.
main.8d7f0b54d7450531.js:1 Using the ES5 version of the PDF viewer. Your PDF files show faster if you update your browser.
/assets/pdf-2.16.450-es5.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

[image]

code :

`

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer 
        [src]='url' 
        [useBrowserLocale]="true" 
        height="100vh">
        [textLayer]="true"
        [showHandToolButton]="true"
        [showPresentationModeButton]="true"
        [showDownloadButton]="false"
    </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

`

package.Json:

{
"name": "ecaaf",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^14.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
"ag-grid-angular": "^28.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^28.2.0",
"angular-confirmation-popover": "^6.0.0",
"angular-google-charts": "^2.2.3",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
"html2pdf.js": "^0.9.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.1",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.2",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.1",
"ngx-easy-table": "^15.3.0",
"ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^15.0.10",
"ngx-toastr": "^15.2.2",
"pdfjs-dist": "^3.0.279",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.5",
"@angular/cli": "~14.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
"jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.7.2"
}
}

Angular.JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ecaaf": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["",
            "moment-business",
            "ng2-pdf-viewer",
            "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf",
            "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer"],
            "outputPath": "dist/ecaaf",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
               
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "20mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "20mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ecaaf:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ecaaf:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ecaaf:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use the latest version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer, angular 14
Browser google chrome latest update

Answer (score 1):

you haven't closed your opening tag:

> <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

with a ">"

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem.  I have narrowed it down to the fact that our organization's web servers don't have the .mjs (Module Javascript) extension set up with a MIME Type.  Therefore the server doesn't serve up the files used by ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.

The MIME Type should be Text/Javascript.

This can be proved by running http-server locally to run my site.  It (and GitHub pages) have the correct MIME Types setup and recognize/serve up the files.

Hopefully I can get our server folks to add this in short order.

Good luck on your end.

Dan